# Split VFR video into CFR chunks?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-editing, avisynth

Is there a good way to split a VFR video into chunks that split whenever the framerate changes?

I have a video that I want to edit that is VFR but my editor doesn't support VFR. I don't want to set a constant framerate and convert it because that could degrade some sections of the video.

I was thinking that one way working with it would be to take it and split it into chunks that are CFR to work on separately (hopefully they'll be large sections).

I haven't found a good way to do it though, ffmpeg at least doesn't seem to have something built in to let me do it.

An alternative question would be: is there some software that would let me easily scan the video to find the framerates used? If it's not too crazy, I can convert to a common multiple framerate, edit and then remove the duplicate frames with Avisynth later.

Comment: If you want to make a lot of changes then there's probably no need to split the video - you can edit it whole in CFR-assumed mode and then apply the timecodes from the original video to the rendered result.

Comment: As for finding VFR ranges, look for an exact command line by googling "how to extract timecodes" and depending on the method the result will be a V1 format that lists the ranges (this is what you need) or V2 format that lists the frames (you'll need to find a converter from V2 to V1).

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll look into extracting the timecodes (Avisynth mentions doing so in a separate tutorial). Based on a quick look with MediaInfo, I could see segment information embedded in the file in a way that seems to be V2, so I'll work on getting that stripped out and converted.

Comment: Also on the CFR-assumed mode, how would the timecodes apply? If I deleted a chunk from the middle of the video wouldn't the timecodes get messed up since the frames won't match or is there a way to work with them that'll be aware of the edits?

Comment: Indeed, deleting/inserting won't work with my first suggestion.

Comment: The assumption here seems to be that a VFR file is composed of sections which are piecemeal CFR. That's not usually the case. Typical case.is that per-frame duration differs across the stream.

Comment: @Gyan I had hoped it was the case because it had reason to be that way. After getting the timecodes extracted properly (I followed a tutorial that had me extracting timecodes from the wrong track) and converting them, I found out that it definitely is how you describe it with tons of very small sections.